# Help with XYZ math surface syntax

Tags: python, mesh

I'm trying to model a 'super egg' in Blender. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superegg

When sweeping the curve, the formulas for X and Y should be

```
X = abs(cos(t)**(2/2.5)) * sign(cos(t))
Y = abs(sin(t)**(2/2.5)) * sign(sin(t))
```

I'm having trouble translating those into the format that Blender wants.

I assume that it's Python syntax, so first I tried to solve that there doesn't seem to be a 'sign' function.
So I added this in the 'A helper function'

`0 if cos(u) == 0 else -1 if cos(u) < 0 else 1`

When I then put `abs(cos(u))**0.8*a` into the formula for X, Blender gives me the error message `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` which I can't make sense of.

Any help will be appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: I've fiddled around a bit with it. If I have the X formula as `cos(u)` it works. If I change it to `abs(cos(u))` it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the `abs` function.

I opened up the script that creates the mesh ("..\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\addons\add_mesh_extra_objects\add_mesh_3d_function_surface.py"). It has a list of 'accepted' functions at the top and `abs` isn't included. However `fabs` is. When I changed the formula for X to `fabs(cos(u))**0.8*a` it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in the code that processes that string, which you did not include. "NoneType object is not subscriptable" means that you try to access a variable that is None with a subscription operator ([]) which is not anywhere in the code you presented here, so I assume the problem is elsewhere. This commonly happens when you expect a method of an object to return itself, e.g.

```
# correct
some_list = [1, 2, 3]
some_list.sort()
result = some_list[0]

# wrong
some_list = [1, 2, 3]
result = some_list.sort()[0] # TypeError, since sort method returns None.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't have any Python code I've written myself. I tagged it with the python tag because the expression you write in Blender is passed on to Python's `eval` function, so it has to be valid Python syntax.

Comment: Does it error out without the helper function?

Comment: Yes. It seems to be the `abs` function that it doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same for another formula, albeit it only plots positive values since square root of negative value is not a real number.
for `z^2 = x^2 - y^2`:

```
Y eq: u
X eq: v
Z eq: sqrt(fabs(u**2-v**2))
```